# What is available memory while using free command?

Tags: ram, free

The output of the free command that I fired on my linux host is as belows:

```
free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:      263846320    47746620     3290072     1140808   212809628   214382420
Swap:             0           0           0
```

I am not able to figure out what this available part is specifying.
The free memory is very less shown i.e around 1.24% even though the total memory is way high and used memory is around 18.09% only.

```
free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           251G         45G        3.1G        1.1G        202G        204G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

Does it mean I wont be able to start more applications as free memory is very less. The used memory is 18% only. So shouldn't free memory be 72% and not 1.24% as the command is showing above.

I am confused. Can anyone help?

Comment: Cross-posted at https://stackoverflow.com/q/41426656/1310566

Answer (score 96, accepted):

In the output of `free`,

- **Free** memory is the amount of memory which is currently not used for anything. This number should be small, because memory which is not used is simply wasted.
- **Available** memory is the amount of memory which is available for allocation to a new process or to existing processes.

The example given in the question shows a healthy system.

Comment: How the available and buff/cache columns are different from each other.

Comment: @srinivas, `available` does include `free` column + a part of `buff/cache` which can be reused for current needs *immediately*

Comment: this answer convoluted things for me even more

Comment: Yeah I also don't get it... How is the *free* memory different from *available*? Apparently free is a subset of available, but.... what? How? Why? More questions than answers.

Comment: Ok, I just read https://www.linuxatemyram.com/ which explains a lot.

Comment: yes, http://linuxatemyram.com explains it. Available memory is free memory + disk cache memory (which can be released by kernel immediately when needed).

Comment: [Linux server needs a RAM upgrade?](https://haydenjames.io/linux-server-need-ram-upgrade-lets-check-free-top-vmstat-sar) Just adding this link here may be helpful for someone!