# free command shows 7gb of 'free' memory & only 2gb of available memory

Tags: ram, vps, free

when I run the 'free' command it shows my VPS (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS 64bit) as having 8gb total, 7 of which is "free"...

[image: free command result (Gb)]

[image: free command result (Gb decimal)]

[image: free command result (MB)]

[image: free command result (kb)]

From what I understood from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867068/what-is-available-memory-while-using-free-command), free memory is supposed to be very little while available should be a lot more than it is.

How can I find out why this is and fix it?

Comment: Showing in GB gives a very vague incomplete picture due to rounding: some categories here are rounding to 0. You may want to look at it in MB or KB instead.

Comment: Not sure how that would make a difference, but I'll add those as well.

Comment: Please don't post photographies of text when actual text will do. In other words: please use copy&paste to share the output of your commands in text form.

Comment: maybe see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/440185/why-the-available-memory-is-less-than-the-free-memory-in-free-command