# What is the difference between free and available on the system monitor?

Tags: system-monitor

[System Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0s4xM.jpg)

I've searched the [system monitor documentation](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-system-monitor/stable/), but I couldn't find the answer. Is there anyone can help me?

Comment: This answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867068/what-is-available-memory-while-using-free-command) should resolve it for you - though the user in that instance is using the terminal to see the results. The answer is the same for both the terminal and the GUI.

Comment: Note that there's a difference between "free" and "available" in the context of RAM (i.e., equivalent to the output of the `free` command) and in the context of filesystems (i.e., equivalent to the output of the `df` command).

Comment: Thanks to you guys for answering my question. Now I know what the difference is